# Kohana 3.2 Using Auth Module on multiple databases

Tags: kohana, authentication

I'm using the Module Auth with ORM driver and native sessions.

The database config 'default' and 'customer_1' exists in application/config/database.php.

Before login i change the default database config with:

`Kohana::$config->load('database')->default = Kohana::$config->load('database')->get('customer_1');`

This does work before Module Auth login!

After setting the default database config:

`if (Auth::instance()->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) === TRUE) {  Request::current()->redirect(); }`

This results in the following error:

```
Table 'default_database.users' doesn't exist [ SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `users` ]
```

For some reason it use the initial default database config.

My Question: How do i set the default database for Module Auth ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow this through a bit.

You're actually using ORM/Auth and not just Auth.  ORM in ORM/Auth is configured to use the default database if one isn't specified.  It lets you override this option by overloading $_db_group in the ORM.php file.

Let's use Kohana's cascading filesystem to overwrite that.  Make a new file: classes/auth.php .  Insert this code:

```
<?php
class ORM extends Kohana_ORM {
    $_db_group = Kohana::$config->load('database')->get('customer_1');
}
```

All set.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response Gaurav Patel.

The code would be:

<code>
class ORM extends Kohana_ORM {  
 function __construct() {  
  $this->_db_group = Kohana::$config->load('database')->get('customer_1');  
 }  
}  
</code>

But when Auth::instance() is called, this results in an error:

<pre>Class 'Auth' not found</pre>

Comment: Did you load the Auth module in your bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

If you want Auth module to use different database then other models, you should use `$_db_group` as suggested by [Gaurav Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722283/gaurav-patel). However you should override only Auth ORM models (user, role and user_token), not `ORM` class:

APPATH/classes/model/user.php:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User
{
    protected $_db_group = 'customer_1';
}
```

APPATH/classes/model/role.php:

```
class Model_Role extends Model_Auth_Role
{
    protected $_db_group = 'customer_1';
}
```

APPATH/classes/model/user/token.php:

```
class Model_User_Token extends Model_Auth_User_Token
{
    protected $_db_group = 'customer_1';
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! However, how can i change $_db_group before calling Auth::instance()->login() ?

Comment: Extend ORM class, add a setter for `$_db_group` and call it before login

Comment: I've tryed this, but it doesnt do the trick:  
  
APPATH/classes/auth/orm:  
  
`class Auth_ORM extends Kohana_Auth_ORM {  
  
 public function set_db_group($db_group)  
 {  
  $this->_db_group = $db_group;  
 }  
  
}`
  
And before calling `Auth::instance()->login()` :  
  
`Auth::instance()->set_db_group('customer_2');` Also its not that Auth module using a different database then other models, the whole application is changing to a another database, buth Modulde Auth just stick with the default.